# Getting all records based on parent's parent

Tags: sql

This is probably trivial but I can't seem to get it. I'd like to get all the customers of all the stores in a particular area.

```
select * from customers
where customer... ???
... and area = 'downtown'
```

Their relationship:

```
area - 1:M - store - 1:M - customer
```

Comment: You need to JOIN tables here.

Comment: where are the parent here?

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `area` is the parent of `store` which is the parent of `customer`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a subquery.  Assuming this is across two tables then:

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE STORE(ID) IN
    (SELECT STOREID
     FROM STORES
     WHERE AREA = DOWNTOWN)
```